# A doubt with a part of a certain proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Well, in the proof of the following lemma

suppose $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group, and let $C$ a cyclic subgroup of maximal order, then $G=C\oplus H$ for some subgroup $H$

at http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/m317/handouts/finabel.pdf,

They say that since $H\cap(C+K)= K$, we have $H\cap C=\{e\}$. But how do they have that

**this part $H\cap(C+K)= K$**?

Can someone prove that please is because I don't see why is that true with the arguments presented in that proof.

**I have the following attempt :**

We know that $G/K=(C+K)/K \cong H' \Rightarrow H \cap (C+K)=K$

If there is $x \in H \cap C, x \neq e,$ then $H \cap (C + K) = K \Rightarrow x \in K.$ But by your assumption $C\cap K = \{e\}$

more precisely :

I want to prove (convincing myself), why is this rght. In the proof of the lemma

suppose $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group, and let $C$ a cyclic subgroup of maximal order, then $G=C\oplus H$ for some subgroup $H$

at http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/m317/handouts/finabel.pdf

they have that since $H\cap(C+K)= K$, we have $H\cap C=\{e\}$. But how do they have **the part of** $H\cap(C+K)= K$? is because they say that $H'$ is the preimage of a certain map, then they can do the following:

$G/K= (C+K)/K \oplus H/K$

but I do not know if that is enough to justificate that step, or how can they have the conclusion that  $H\cap(C+K)= K$,and well the part that $H\cap C=\{e\}$ is obvious from here, and in the proof of the same lemma they say that because $K$ has prime order then $K\cap C=\{e\}$,  is that the only reason? Can someone prove those things please is because I don't see why is that true with the arguments presented in that proof. Thanks in advance.

**I am back in the discussion and I have edited my post to be clearler :)**

Comment: You haven't told us what $K$ is.

Comment: well in the link say that, but is a subgroup of G of order p :)

Comment: @WillO Why no one anwers, what is wrong with my question? thanks :)

Comment: I am here in the discussion, but the thing is why do no one answers to may question, what is wrong?

Comment: I am sorry for this but my doubt was in the part that I pst here and in the other question the answer was to other thing :)

Comment: I am back in the discussion an I have edited my post to be clearler :)

Answer (score 1):

If there is $x \in H \cap C, x \neq e,$ then $H \cap (C + K) = K \Rightarrow x \in K.$ But by your assumption $C\cap K = \{e\}$

Let $h = c + k \in H \cap (C + K), c \neq e.$ Then $c = h - k \in H \Rightarrow c + K = h + K$ is a non-trivial element in $((C + K)/K) \cap (H/K)$ which contradicts the fact that $G/K = (C + K)/K \oplus H/K.$

Comment: And the conclusion follows, or how you conclude

Comment: if there is a non-identity element in $H \cap C$, then we are getting that $C \cap K \neq \{e\},$ a contradiction.

Comment: yes that is right, and we are done isnt?

Comment: yes! we are done.

Comment: Ok I thought is was more difficult :), thanks for the proof :)

Comment: I am sorry the problem was in the part that I bolded above :), thanks a lot for your answer even that :)

Comment: @user162343: I've edited my answer accordingly. I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Can you tell me if I am rght with my post above plaese :)

Comment: I have edited my post to make it clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $G/K=(C+K)/K\oplus  H/K$ so

$G=(C+K)+H$ and $(C+K)\cap H=\phi$